# Does knockout.js support binding between html elements?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Does knockout.js support binding bettwen html elements without a viewmodel, like Silverlight/Wpf element binding?

Example:
I have a form and I'd like to show/hide fields based on the value of one field (a checkbox).

Is there a simple way of making that work with knockout or going with pure javascript would be more straight forward?

I'm trying to implement a reusable way of doing that based on data-attributes but it's starting to become cumbersome and I started wondering if knockout would be the way to go to make it reusable.

Comment: I don't think knockout supports binding between html elements. Even if it did, you should create an underlying observable in js, and bind your html elements to it. I am giving the question a +1 to offset the downvote some [...] gave it. Not entirely an unreasonable question.

Comment: I have some background in Silverlight and WPF, and consequently MVVM development, but I'm starting developing in HTML/JS now. I have not started using knockout yet, just played with it a little. In this particular case, I stumbled with that form and, as I imagine I'll hit that case again in another pages, I wondered if knockout would support some features XAML did. I couldn't find information on the case in the documentation, so I asked it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without a ViewModel but you can do this with computed variables:

```
//In your view model
this.showFormElement = ko.computed(function(){
    if(this.checkboxValueiswhatIwant()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}, this);
```

then in your html:

```
<form [id, classes, etc..]>
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checkboxValueiswhatIwant" />
    <input type="input" data-bind="visible: showFormElement" />
</form>
```

Out of general curiosity how are you using knockout without a view model?

If you are using it somehow, why?

Comment: I'm not. My current approach consists in pure js, searching fields by id and subscribing to onchange events.

Comment: Well yeah I assumed you were using knockout...this is kind of the stuff it was built for, this updating the UI based on events.  If you do use it the code I gave you there will work.

Comment: You don't technically need the computed. Just add the `checked` binding to the checkbox and use that observable for the `visible` binding on the other element.

Comment: True probably should though that through a little more, but he could also use the computed if he wants to get more technical (which you could still do in the bindings but would get cluttered rather quickly).

Comment: For now I'm gonna stick with pure JS, but I believe that yours would be the way to go with Knockout. Thanks